# Windows PCs arping excessively for Domain Controller because they don't like the gateway given by DHCP

Tags: windows, networking, dhcp, gateway

I've been administering my company's network for about 20 years. This is the first time this has ever happened and I've exhausted all means including my external network consultant and firewall support.

**The Problem**

The problem arose about 3-4 weeks ago. There were no firmware of config updates on any firewalls or switches since a few months before this. At first, employees started complaining that Windows login was a bit slower than usual (our login time is normally 1-5 seconds to desktop). Then a few days later it got really slow, taking up to a minute, and other AD related operations like accessing files in the file server got really slow as well. Until the point where one morning no one could work at all. I narrowed it down to pretty much anything having to check for auth on the on-prem DCs because other non-AD comms seemed to be unnafected. Also, in my desperation, I restarted switches and firewall and it seems to have temporarily fixed the problem for a few days.

**Research**

I first contacted my external network consultant who designed and maintains the more advanced stuff in my network. He thought it might be a loop of some sort in one of the switches. But checking logs and observing behavior more carefully he realized it wasnt a loop. User desktops are in a separate network that has to go through a firewall to get to the internal interface where the servers are. And we were observing that the issue only happened when going through the firewall. When we connected a desktop directly to the core switches, the issue didnt happen. So I opened a ticket with my firewall vendor. They looked around and saw nothing wrong (typical).

So I kept doing my own research and found something interesting. From my firewall, I sniffed all arp packets during a login, and I noticed that during the entire minute it was trying to log in, the PC was going crazy doing arp requests for the Domain Controller and of course no one was replying. From my limited network knowledge, I know it shouldnt be doing that because the DC is not in its subnet and also because it should be sending all other traffic to the gateway no questions asked, right? Why did it forget where the DC was? The `ipconfig /all` command shows the gateway and everything else is set correctly. But eventually it logs in and does everything fine--it's not disconnected, it's just slow.

**Surprise**

Now, my network consultant had an idea and told me to try and disable DHCP on a PC and set the same network settings manually. I thought that was going to be kinda pointless, but to my surprise, the issue didnt happen! During login, there were no arp requests, and it logged on in 5 seconds. We went back and forth a few times and on different PCs and proved that this only happens when it's on DHCP. The `ipconfig` settings show exactly the same values! It's like all PCs stopped liking the gateway the DHCP assigns them but they have no problem with the manual gateway. He was just as suprised as me and really has no idea what's happening. Firewall support is also stumped.

Does anyone have any clue what could be causing this?

**Edit:**

```
*workstation - ipconfig /all*
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E4-B9-7A-EF-3F-6C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5959:44b:7b64:b2b3%22(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.158(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, August 3, 2022 3:40:11 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, August 11, 2022 3:40:11 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.21
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 132430202
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-24-EC-CE-42-E4-B9-7A-EF-3F-6C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.21
                                       10.1.1.22
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled


*workstation - route print*
===========================================================================
Interface List
 22...e4 b9 7a ef 3f 6c ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM
  7...38 00 25 47 d2 40 ......Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
 21...38 00 25 47 d2 41 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #5
 12...3a 00 25 47 d2 40 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #6
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.2.1     10.0.2.158     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
       10.0.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      10.0.2.158    281
     10.0.2.158  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.0.2.158    281
     10.0.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.0.2.158    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.0.2.158    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.0.2.158    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 22    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 22    281 fe80::5959:44b:7b64:b2b3/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 22    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None


*domain controller - ipconfig /all*
Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-A1-04-EB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b53d:32:2381:b7d3%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.21(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.22
                                       127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: Some questions - what is the switch(es), what is the firewall, and what is your DHCP config being sent to the clients?

Comment: Relatedly - post itpconfig /all from a DHCP workstation, and from your DC

Comment: What do you mean it was doing ARP requests for the DC? Just to confirm, are you saying that the desktop was asking “who has <IP of the DC>?” How many domain controllers do you have? When trying to reach the DC, first there should be a DNS request for the domain name, which the DNS server should be the same as the DC.  We need to see `ipconfig /all` output and probably a `route` output. And what are the IPs of the DCs? What you are describing is typically a DNS issue. No offense but I am just a little concerned you are interpreting your packet capture wrong.

Comment: What is providing DHCP services to the PCs? I’m going to guess that the firewall in the middle is a problem because it is interrupting the DHCP or DNS functionality. The ARP behavior could be related to some type of DHCP relay you have turned on with the firewall, assuming DHCP is installed on one of the DCs.

Comment: I don't feel comfortable disclosing switch and firewall brands publicly. I posted ipconfigs and routing tables (replaced some octects for privacy). Yes, the workstations were doing arp who-has <ip of dc>. `USERS in arp who-has 10.0.1.21 tell 10.0.2.158` About 3 of those per second from a single workstation. The DC ip was correct so the dns resolved the ip just fine. The DC is serving DHCP and we relay it through the firewall interface. This is interesting, why do you think the firewall might be interrupting the DHCP if the config is getting to the workstations correctly?

Comment: The DC ips are the same as the DNS servers listed there in the workstation ipconfig.

Comment: If it helps, my physical path from users to dc goes like this:
`desktop > access_switch > firewall_users_port > firewall_internal_port > core_switch > dc`

Comment: I only remember the arp storm after a DC replacement. it had also somekind of wins server and some clients were still related to it. please also provide the full message from the firewall to the question

Comment: It's not clear, but I have three questions. Do the slow logins occur AFTER the computer has already been logged in to once before? Or, it is only slow after a reboot? Second, when "nobody could work" did you get a login error message - something along the line of no domain controller available? Third, when file access was slow, was this intermittently or all the time? The best place to look would be the windows event log during the startup / logon window, and network tracing requires a wholistic look, not just focusing on ARPs. Something we aren't able to do without the captures.

Comment: The reason why we ask for model numbers is to understand the equipment you are working with and to know if there are any nuances which may clue us in to the problem. You’ve indicated the ARP happens when DHCP is enabled. In the packet did you confirm that the source MAC address actually matches the workstation’s MAC address? How do you know the packet is coming from the workstation. With that said, there might be some type of DHCP relay, or perhaps an ARP proxy configuration that is misbehaving on the “firewall.” That’s my best guess. It’s a complex problem that I need more insight in to.